# Change or localize app name for already published app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app with an app name in my native language (not english). Now I would like to change so that the app gets an international name. I have seen that this can be done for the app name that is shown in the phones app list and tile, but can it also be done for the app name shown in the Marketplace?

So if the user is in language A, then the app name should be App A.
In all other cases (english, german, french...) the name should be App B.

If this can't be done. Can I simply change the name of the app for all users?

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allowed to specify a different name for each language you support on the marketplace. The supported languages is determined by the availability of Resource files matching the languages.

So if you add:

- Resources.en.resx
- Resources.de.resx
- Resources.fr.resx

You'll get the ability to type in marketplace descriptions, and seperate name/graphics in English, German and French.

Comment: Alright! So this means that if an english user searches for my app in the Marketplace a different name will be shown than if a french user does the same (if I have resources as you specified)? Can I change the name of the app for all markets aswell, sort of like changing the default name displayed in Marketplace?

Comment: Yes. And regarding changing the name, you'll see what you can change once you submit the app. It's hard for me to predict if you can change the current name.

Comment: Alright, cool! Will give it a try. Does anyone know if this will mess up all the ratings of the app or will the name change in Marketplace go seamlessly?

Comment: It won't affect any ratings, but remember that ratings are only visible for the users own marketplace, not globally.